# Error con la generacion de query viewers

Tags: genexus

estoy teniendo problemas con el armado de la consulta que generan los query viewers. En varios me pasa que me agrega un campo 'F1' que después no especifica cual es en la consulta. Paso ejemplo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto claramente en ejecución me da error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy trabajando con v18 u6 con .net y mysql

Saludos, gracias!